# Form posting before ajax can update content

Tags: forms, ajax, webforms

My form is submitting faster than ajax can update my textarea. How can I delay the form from submitting so the ajax can update my textarea?

```
$form['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
'callback' => 'getCampaignString',
'event' => 'submit',
'wrapper' => 'Comments_replace',
'method' => 'replace',
);
$form['submitted']['Comments']['#prefix'] = '<div id="Comments_replace">';
$form['submitted']['Comments']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

 function getCampaignString(&$form, &$form_state){
    $campaingString = $form_state['values']['submitted']['campaignstring'];
    $comments = $form_state['values']['submitted']['Comments'];
    $comments = $comments."[".$campaingString."]";
    $form['submitted']['Comments'] = $comments;

    $form['submitted']['Comments'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => t('New Comments'),
        '#name' => 'submitted[Comments]',
        '#value' => $form['submitted']['Comments'],
    );

    return $form['submitted']['Comments'];

}
```

So basically I have this webform for getting leads. There is a textarea for comments on the form. What I need to do is append a string to the end of the comments text on POST. For example: Say they made a comment like "I want more information" and when they hit submit. I need to add a string to the end of the comments so in the post it will look like this: I want more information - campaignName. The only way I have found to add my campaingname to the post of the comments is to replace the textarea with the new information in it but I cannot seem to replace it fast enought when submitted.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I have no clue what you want. Please outline the functionality of your form, what should it do? And what is the situation that doesn't work for you?

Comment: So basically I have this webform for getting leads. There is a textarea for comments on the form. What I need to do is append a string to the end of the comments text on POST. For example: Say they made a comment like "I want more information" and when they hit submit. I need to add a string to  the end of the comments so in the post it will look like this: I want more information - campaignName. The only way I have found to add my campaingname to the post of the comments is to replace the textarea with the new information in it but I cannot seem to replace it fast enought when submitted.

Comment: @Django You should be doing that processing on the server side, either in a validate or submit handler for the form. Relying on the speed of a user's browser (which is what you're unintentionally doing here) isn't going to be reliable

Comment: @Clive - Doing in the validation worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'webform_validate';
}

function webform_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  //Appending comments field with campaignString
  $campaingString = $form_state['values']['submitted']['campaignstring'];
  $comments = $form_state['values']['submitted']['Comments'];
  $comments = "[".$campaingString."]  " . $comments;
  $form_state['values']['submitted']['Comments'] = $comments;
}
```